# Print information about which property caused mocha AssertionError

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

Given the following unit test:

```
var object = {
    a: [],
    b: [],
    c: null,
    d: [],
    e: []
};

describe('Multiple assertions', () => {
    it("Should be all arrays", (done) => {
        expect(object).to.have.property('a').that.is.a('array');
        expect(object).to.have.property('b').that.is.a('array');
        expect(object).to.have.property('c').that.is.a('array');
        expect(object).to.have.property('d').that.is.a('array');
        expect(object).to.have.property('e').that.is.a('array');
        done();
    });
});
```

It correctly fails on one of the properties not being an array but it's unclear from the output which property caused the test to fail:

```
  1) Multiple assertions
       Should be all arrays:
     AssertionError: expected null to be an array
      at Context.it (server/test/serverTest.js:27:48)
```

Is it possible for mocha to print a more descritive output such as below?

```
For property 'c' expected null to be an array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `try {} catch {}` your `expect()` functions and format the error yourself. But I'm not sure it is the optimal way to answer this question.

Comment: Yes, I guess in the worst case I could. I'm wondering if there is even a more elegant solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an elegant way to do it thanks to this post:

[How to provide chai expect with custom error message for mocha unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678706/how-to-provide-chai-expect-with-custom-error-message-for-mocha-unit-test)

Modified my test this way:

```js
describe('Multiple assertions', () => {
    it("Should be all arrays", (done) => {
        expect(object, '"a" should be an array').to.have.property('a').that.is.a('array');
        expect(object, '"b" should be an array').to.have.property('b').that.is.a('array');
        expect(object, '"c" should be an array').to.have.property('c').that.is.a('array');
        expect(object, '"d" should be an array').to.have.property('d').that.is.a('array');
        expect(object, '"e" should be an array').to.have.property('e').that.is.a('array');
        done();
    });
});
```

The result is:

```
1) Multiple assertions
     Should be all arrays:
     AssertionError: "c" should be an array: expected null to be an array
at Context.it (server/test/serverTest.js:27:48)
```